# Merge Raster with SpatialLinesDataFrame

Tags: r, maps, spatial, r-raster

I need to load a raster map and a `.shp` file.

both are loaded into the global environment in the following way

```
library(raster)
library(maptools)
library(maps)
topo <- raster("topo Europe.tif")
roads <- readShapeSpatial("roman_roads_v2008.shp")
```

Now I have both in the global environment. I can plot them independently

```
plot(plot(topo, col=gray.colors(100), axes=F, box=F, legend=F))
plot(roads)
```

however I can only see one of the two even if I try to plot them together like this

```
plot(plot(topo, col=gray.colors(100), axes=F, box=F, legend=F))
plot(roads)
```

I tried to merge using

```
topo.crs <- CRS(projection(topo))
roadstopo <- spTransform(roads, topo.crs)
```

But I get this error message.

> Error in spTransform(xSP, CRSobj, ...) : 
>     No transformation possible from NA reference system

Is there any way to either merge them or to plot on over the other?

**Object information**

```
# roads

class       : SpatialLinesDataFrame 
features    : 7154 
extent      : -1671176, 2800340, -587294.7, 3042248  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
variables   : 7
names       : OBJECTID,      CLASS, CERTAINTY, PERIOD, HYPERLINK, SOURCE,   Shape_Leng 
min values  :        1, Major Road,        No,     NA,        NA,   150K,     22.07838 
max values  :     8900, Minor Road,       YES,     NA,        NA,    TIB, 362192.17666 



# Topo
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 4320, 6480, 27993600  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : -13, 41, 29, 65  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs 
data source : C:\Users\Mathew\OneDrive\Archaology\Dissertation\R work\topo_Europe.tif 
names       : topo_Europe 
values      : -422, 4536  (min, max)
```

Now

`projection(roads)<- "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs"`

**Object information**

```
# roads

class       : SpatialLinesDataFrame 
features    : 7154 
extent      : -1671176, 2800340, -587294.7, 3042248  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs 
variables   : 7
names       : OBJECTID,      CLASS, CERTAINTY, PERIOD, HYPERLINK, SOURCE,   Shape_Leng 
min values  :        1, Major Road,        No,     NA,        NA,   150K,     22.07838 
max values  :     8900, Minor Road,       YES,     NA,        NA,    TIB, 362192.17666 



# Topo
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 4320, 6480, 27993600  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : -13, 41, 29, 65  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs 
data source : C:\Users\Mathew\OneDrive\Archaology\Dissertation\R work\topo_Europe.tif 
names       : topo_Europe 
values      : -422, 4536  (min, max)
```

They have the same projection however are not plotting together. Plotting either first and then adding the other is processed however nothing is visible. Is the error in how I am plotting?

`plot(topo, col=gray.colors(100), axes=F, box=F, legend=F)
with(roads, add=T)`

Comment: While merging and plotting them together is an entirely different thing, the latter should be easily achieved (assuming they overlap) with setting `add` in `plot` to `TRUE` - in your case `plot(roads,add = T)` after you already plotted the raster

Comment: This didn't work in my case. I suspect they don't overlap. Both are focused on Europe. Would there be a way to map the .shp to Latitude/Longitude or the same x/y as the raster

Comment: Can you add the object information for both raster and roads to your question? Simply run the objects in the console and copy the output

Comment: Added into question

Comment: seems like `roads` is in a different projection ... you need to add the correct coordinate reference to it an ten project both datasets into a common projection

Comment: Your layers do not have the same projection. Look at the coordinates, the extent is not the same at all. You need to find out what is the original projection of your roads shapefile and then reproject it using `spTransform` (and never use `projection(roads) <- something`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Val said the projection was wrong. Corrected and posted

```
roads <- shapefile("roman_roads_v2008.shp")
roadstrue <- spTransform(roads, crs(topo)) #Centers roads to topo
plot(topo, col=gray.colors(100), axes=F, box=F, legend=F, colNA="white")
plot(roadstrue, add= T)
```

resulting in this plot [image]